# Floating point math rounding weird in C++ compared to mathematica

Tags: c++, c++11, wolfram-mathematica, random

**The following post is solved,the problem occurred because of miss interpretation of the formula on http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/piecewise_constant_distribution/  The reader is strongly encouraged to consider the page: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/piecewise_constant_distribution**

I have the following strange phenomenon which puzzles me!:

I have a **piecewise constant probability density** given as

```
using RandomGenType = std::mt19937_64;
RandomGenType gen(51651651651);

using PREC = long double;
std::array<PREC,5> intervals {0.59, 0.7, 0.85, 1, 1.18};
std::array<PREC,4> weights {1.36814, 1.99139, 0.29116, 0.039562};

 // integral over the pdf to normalize:
PREC normalization =0;
for(unsigned int i=0;i<4;i++){
    normalization += weights[i]*(intervals[i+1]-intervals[i]);
}
std::cout << std::setprecision(30) << "Normalization: " << normalization << std::endl;
// normalize all weights (such that the integral gives 1)!
for(auto & w : weights){
    w /= normalization;
}

std::piecewise_constant_distribution<PREC>
distribution (intervals.begin(),intervals.end(),weights.begin());
```

When I draw `n` random numbers (radius of sphere in millimeters) from this distribution and compute the mass of the sphere and sum them up like:

```
unsigned int n = 1000000;
double density = 2400;
double mass = 0;

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    auto d = 2* distribution(gen) * 1e-3;
    mass += d*d*d/3.0*M_PI_2*density;
}
```

I get **mass = 4.3283 kg**  (see LIVE [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c9d062f5153ce9e))

Doing the EXACT identical thing in Mathematica like:

[image: Graphic]

Gives the assumably correct value of **4.5287 kg**. (see [mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76444/random-numbers-in-c-and-mathematica-gives-wrong-results/76448#76448))

Which is not the same, also with different seeds , C++ and Mathematica never match! ? Is that numeric inaccuracy, which I doubt it is...?
**Question : What the hack is wrong with the sampling in C++?**

**Simple Mathematica Code:**

```
pdf[r_] = 2*Piecewise[{{0, r < 0.59}, {1.36814, 0.59 <= r <= 0.7}, 
           {1.99139, Inequality[0.7, Less, r, LessEqual, 0.85]}, 
           {0.29116, Inequality[0.85, Less, r, LessEqual, 1]}, 
           {0.039562, Inequality[1, Less, r, LessEqual, 1.18]}, 
           {0, r > 1.18}}];

pdfr[r_] = pdf[r] / Integrate[pdf[r], {r, 0, 3}];(*normalize*)

Plot[pdf[r], {r, 0.4, 1.3}, Filling -> Axis]

PDFr = ProbabilityDistribution[pdfr[r], {r, 0, 1.18}]; 
(*if you put 1.18=2 then we dont get 4.52??*)

SeedRandom[100, Method -> "MersenneTwister"]
dataR = RandomVariate[PDFr, 1000000, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision];
Fold[#1 + (2*#2*10^-3)^3  Pi/6 2400 &, 0, dataR] 

(*Analytical Solution*)

PDFr = ProbabilityDistribution[pdfr[r], {r, 0, 3}];
1000000 Integrate[ 2400 (2 InverseCDF[PDFr, p] 10^-3)^3 Pi/6, {p, 0, 1}]
```

**Update**:
I did some analysis:

1. Read in the numbers (64bit doubles) generated from Mathematica into
   C++ -> calculated the sum and it gives the same as Mathematica
   **Mass computed by reduction: 4.52528010260687096888432279229**
2. Read in the numbers generated from C++ (64bit double) into Mathematica -> calculated the sum and it gives the same **4.32402**
3. I almost conclude the sampling with `std::piecewise_constant_distribution` is inaccurate (or as accurate as it gets with 64bit floats) or has a bug... OR there is something wrong with my weights?
4. Densities are calculated wrongly `std::piecewise_constant_distribution` in http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca171bf600b5148f ===> It seems to be a bug!

**Histogramm Plot of CPP Generated values compared to the wanted Distribution:**
    [image: Histogramm]

```
file = NotebookDirectory[] <> "numbersCpp.bin";
dataCPP = BinaryReadList[file, "Real64"];
Hpdf = HistogramDistribution[dataCPP];
h = DiscretePlot[  PDF[ Hpdf, x], {x, 0.4, 1.2, 0.001}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[h, p, PlotRange -> All]
```

The file is generated here: [Number generation CPP](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f39a37b8cec9116)

Comment: What do you mean by "with different seeds I never get the same"? Why would you get the same total of a sum of random numbers if the random numbers are different in each case?

Comment: Sorry that is missunderstanding, its never the same of course, but the results never match! (edit this)

Comment: With all the arbitrary constants and formulas going on here, it might take a while for people to sift through it and find the problem.  It would be better if you could simplify your code as much possible.  Maybe you made a simple typo in one of the numbers, and you would find it by simplifying.

Comment: You are right, I am still looking at it, i simplified as much as possible, I am still trying to make it more simple, but thats what it boils down to...

Comment: Simplifed the C++ code,

Comment: How is that anywhere near "as much as possible".  Have you shown it does or does not happen with 2 intervals?  Even one interval?

Comment: You should histogram the random numbers generated by your C++ code and compare them to the expected pdf. That can help to further diagnose what's going on.

Comment: Jeah, may be, its is strange tough why Mathematica has such a huge difference compared to the C++ version (for me this is critical!)

Comment: When I randomize the seed, your code gives results in the range 4.32788 kg - 4.33053 kg though, so you're right that there's a quirk somewhere.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80f1ed73907c6032  My money is on floating-point inaccuracy.

Comment: C++ piecewise_constant_distribution looks good to me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbb514454ade1597 all ranges found within a fifth of a percent of expectation.

Comment: I added some Reduction step, to sum up all values (it does not help)

Comment: @Mooing Duck: The test is good, but it seems there is some accuracy error in the standart library implementation of gcc

Comment: also ``boost::random::piecewise_constant_distribution`` gives the same
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc44a501ccc0564d

Comment: @Gabriel: That's pretty much proof right there that it's not the fault of piecewise_constant_distribution sampling and is entirely due to floating point rounding.  The problem is this line here: `mass += d*d*d/3.0*M_PI_2*density;`

Comment: ok, but then how can mathematica be more precise (or unprecise who knows) , it also works with machine precision as set by the algorithm, that sucks :-)

Comment: @Gabriel: Are you sure you didn't want `std::piecewise_linear_distribution` it approximates much closer to what Mathematica has

Comment: mathematica is correct: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76444/random-numbers-in-c-and-mathematica-gives-wrong-results/76448#76448

Comment: @ AndyG:  piecewise_linear are linear functions , how can you moddel jumps with linear function, that does not work, I think piecewise_constant is the correct distribution

Comment: @ Mooing Duck: I also tried to do the accumulation with a reduction: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/727b6bc4d0118af2 which unfortunately did not help to increase accuracy

Comment: ``long double`` does not help : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a8131c4da0ee473

Comment: @Jongware What is `std`s random? [`std::piecewise_constant_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/piecewise_constant_distribution): "*produces random floating-point numbers, which are uniformly distributed within each of the several subintervals*". And Mooing duck checked it looks ok.

Comment: Surprised that no one asked which compiler and standard library was used and their versions.

Comment: gcc, clang  on ubuntu (clang uses the gcc 4.8.2 standart library)

Comment: dump the c generated values to a file, read into mathematica and start generating histograms to validate the distribution. also let mathematica sum them up to see if the precision is the issue.  the difference is order 10^-7 per value, a bit big to pass off as a simple floading point problem.

Comment: Read in the numbers (64bit doubles) generated from Mathematica into C++ -> calculated the sum ->  and it gives the same as Mathematica
**Mass computed by reduction:                             4.52528010260687096888432279229**
Next is the inverse, read in the numbers into Mathematica

Comment: OK Folks: **The densities are calculated wrongly in ``std::piecewise_constant_distribution`` or am I nuts!???**
See here for a simple example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca171bf600b5148f

Answer (score 2):

[The following paragraph was edited for correctness. --Editor's note]

Mathematica may or may not use IEEE 754 floating point numbers.  From the Wolfram documentation:

> The Wolfram Language has sophisticated built-in automatic numerical precision and accuracy control. But for special-purpose optimization of numerical computations, or for studying numerical analysis, the Wolfram Language also allows detailed control over precision and accuracy.

and

> The Wolfram Language handles both integers and real numbers with any number of digits, automatically tagging numerical precision when appropriate. The Wolfram Language internally uses several highly optimized number representations, but nevertheless provides a uniform interface for digit and precision manipulation, while allowing numerical analysts to study representation details when desired.

Comment: I am just doing a test if the random numbers generated form mathematica (64 bit doubles)

Comment: "C++ uses IEEE 754 floating point numbers" - no, it doesn't have to.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the formula for the probabilities is wrongly written for  `std::piecewise_constant_distribution` on
 http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/piecewise_constant_distribution/

The summation of the weights is done without the interval lengths multiplied!

**The correct formula is:** 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/piecewise_constant_distribution

This solves every stupid quirk previously discovered as bug/floating point error and so on!

Comment: This is incorrect. The densities returned by `piecewise_constant_distribution::densities()` are scaled by the width of their corresponding intervals. Your calculations do not take this into account. In your example, the second interval should have a density four times that of the first, because its weight is twice the weight of the first's and the interval is half the width of the first. This relationship holds as expected for the densities returned by `piecewise_constant_distribution`, but it does not for your calculations.

Comment: Jason you should remove this comment, as it does not apply anymore to the post. Thanks for the very good input, maybee add it on top